# Check if control is a TextBox

Tags: c++, winforms, controls

I am using C++ Winforms. So I have a `Control` in my form.

Now what I want to do is something like this to check if a control is a `TextBox`:

```
if (control is TextBox)
{
    // ...
}
```

In C# you can do the above I believe. But how can I do the same in C++ Winforms?

Comment: E.g., `for each (Control^ ctl in this->Controls) { if (ctl->GetType() == TextBox::typeid) { /* Do something... */  } }` --  I assume you mean C++/CLI

Answer (score 0):

As said by [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/126795518?noredirect=1), this can be done as follows:

```
for each (Control^ control in this->Controls)
{
    if (control->GetType() == TextBox::typeid)
    {
        // control is a TextBox
    }
}
```